# Wrong positioned menu buttons (sometimes)

Tags: bug

Sometimes when switching the page the menu buttons appear at the wrong place, when I click them or go to a new page they "jump" back.

It happens seemingly random, I encountered it a few times (2-3 times in the last few days).

[image]

I'm using Firefox 53 (32bit) on Windows 10 64bit (anniversary update), if that's important.

I have NoScript and Firebug as active add-ons, no userscripts enabled.

Comment: What OS (and version)? Do you have any add-ons/plugins/extensions/users scripts installed? If so, what happens if you disable them? Do you see this happening again?

Comment: I have NoScript and Firebug as addons. I can disable them and see if it happens again. A bit tricky because it happens very rarely and I haven't found a way to reproduce it.

Comment: @Oded It just happened again (and all add-ons were disabled).