# Documentation Pioneer differently aligned on badges help page

Tags: bug, design, badges, help-center

When I open [the badges help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) the Documentation Pioneer badge seems unaligned compared to the other badges:

[image: Screenshot that shows that the badge is differently aligned compared to the other badges]

Is that something others can verify? (I had [some other seemingly unaligned buttons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348441/wrong-positioned-menu-buttons-sometimes) since the new top-bar was introduced that nobody else saw)

Comment: Which browser? Looks fine for me in FF 53.0.3 (32-Bit) on Win 7.

Comment: I'm using FF (v.53.0.3, no plugins, no extensions)

Comment: Interesting. It happens only at 80% zoom level, when I change it to 90% (or 70%) it looks correct.

Comment: Confirmed, at 80% zoom I see the same problem. Other zoom levels are fine.

Comment: Also happens in Chrome at lower zoom levels. The Documentation Pioneer was not aligned at 67% zoom and the lower the zoom the more badges with longer names get unaligned.

Comment: [Zoom is not supported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280013/4320665).  [Not even on the app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296008/280467)

Comment: That's a shame ...